# Finding exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, exponential-function, generating-functions

A teacher has $n$ students and breaks the students up into some number
of groups. Within each group, they assign one student to be a president and another to be a vice president. Let $t_n$ be the number of ways the teacher can proceed. What's the exponential generating function of $t_n$?

Is this similar to a subline problem where you break the lines in 2 lanes? I'm not sure how to do this one

Answer (score 3):

Where you have a set-up where you partition your set into subsets and impose
a given structure on each of them, the EGF of the total number of arrangements
satisfies $A(x)=\exp(B(x))$ where $B(x)$ is the EGF of the number of structures
that can be put on the subsets.

Here we take an $k$-element set, and designate two of its elements. The number
of ways of doing so is $b_k=k(k-1)$. So
$$B(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{
k(k-1)x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(k-2)!}=x^2e^x.$$
etc.

Comment: I don't understand why you added "etc." is $x^2e^x$ not the generating function?

Comment: @user3427042 "etc." is the cue for you to go on and complete the argument.